# Laravel where clause, and with a list of or's

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a where clause that is an and, with a list of or's. Here's my code:

```
$searchLoop = array(
            'u.Name',
            'u.Email',
            'n.Name',
            'u.PhoneMobile'
        );    
$text = 'Manager';
$count = 0;
        foreach ($searchLoop as $loop) {
            $query->where(function ($where) use ($loop, $count, $text) {
                if ($count === 0) {
                    $where->where($loop, 'like', '%' . $text . '%');
                } else {
                    $where->orWhere($loop, 'like', '%' . $text . '%');
                }
            });
            $count++;
        }
```

Based on my reading of the laravel docs and some other searching, I would expect this to translate like so:

```
and  (
`u`.`Name` like '%Manager%'
or `u`.`Email` like '%Manager%'
or `n`.`Name` like '%Manager%'
or `u`.`PhoneMobile` like '%Manager%'
)
```

Instead, it translates to this:

```
and (`u`.`Name` like '%Manager%')
and (`u`.`Email` like '%Manager%')
and (`n`.`Name` like '%Manager%')
and (`u`.`PhoneMobile` like '%Manager%')
```

Further, it doesn't seem to matter how I play with the $where->where's within the $query->where function(whether I only do orWhere for every loop, etc), it still comes out with just the and's.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to all who helped. I was finally able to figure this out, sticking the foreach inside of the query function solved the problem

```
$query - > where(function($where) use($searchLoop, $text) {
  foreach($searchLoop as $count => $loop) {
    if ($count === 0) {
      $where - > where($loop, 'like', '%'.$text.
        '%');
    } else {
      $where - > orWhere($loop, 'like', '%'.$text.
        '%');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the nested query. How about this? (refactored slightly by Pep Lainez)

```
foreach ($searchLoop as $count => $loop) {
    if ($count === 0) {
        $query = $query->where($loop, 'like', '%' . $text . '%');
    } else {
        $query = $query->orWhere($loop, 'like', '%' . $text . '%');
    }
}
```

Comment: I will change the foreach into foreach($searchLoop as $count => $loop) and you can remove the $count++

Comment: I'm trying to think through the order of operations on this. Would the OR take precedence so that: |and `u`.`Name` like ? or `u`.`Email` like ? or `n`.`Name` like ? or `u`.`PhoneMobile` like ?| and (`u`.`Name` like ? or `u`.`Email` like ? or `n`.`Name` like ? or `u`.`PhoneMobile` like ?) are the same, if after the like queries there's another unrelated AND condition?

Comment: If you do need to group your `where` statements, then you were on the right track with the nested query. Probably need to put the loop inside the closure. But from your example, you'll just have one `where` and several `or where`s.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me (on laravel 5.4);

```
$text = 'Manager';
    $test = User::query()
        ->where('id',1)
        ->where(function($query)use($text){
        $query->where('u.Name','like',"%{$text}%");
        $query->orWhere('u.Email','like',"%{$text}%");
        $query->orWhere('n.name','like',"%{$text}%");
        $query->orWhere('u.PhoneMobile','like',"%{$text}%");
    })->toSql();
```

Which outputs

```
SELECT *
FROM "users"
WHERE "id" = ?
      AND (
        "u"."Name" LIKE ?
        OR "u"."Email" LIKE ?
        OR "n"."name" LIKE ?
        OR "u"."PhoneMobile" LIKE ?
      )
```